# What is the purpose of Uv_clipping in godot?

Tags: uv-mapping, godot-4

Can anyone tell me what is the purpose of uv_clipping property of rendering section in tilemap in godot with example? I don't understand what's the use of this property

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the source code, it seem that aside from passing the argument to virtual methods, it might set a `CANVAS_RECT_CLIP_UV` flag ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/0bcc0e92b3f0ac57d4c4650722f347593a258572/servers/rendering/renderer_canvas_cull.cpp#L1312)) which then translates to a `FLAGS_CLIP_RECT_UV` flag ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/0bcc0e92b3f0ac57d4c4650722f347593a258572/servers/rendering/renderer_rd/renderer_canvas_render_rd.cpp#L550)) which is checked in a shader ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/0bcc0e92b3f0ac57d4c4650722f347593a258572/servers/rendering/renderer_rd/shaders/canvas.glsl#L465)) where it results in clapping the UV coordinates.

*In which situations this makes a difference is unclear to me. My best guess at a glance is that it is related to zooming and culling. Note: it is a 2D feature.*

Addendum: I found an documentation ticket relevant to this: [CanvasItem.draw_texture_rect_region parameter clip_uv doesn't have explanation](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-docs/issues/8292).